# The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable is not a file of a symlink

Tags: python, file, terminal, symlink, interpreter

The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "C:\Users\KAUSTUBH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32" is not a file of a symlink.

i got this error
i m using windows 7 python 3.7.8 vs code have installed python and its extension and write simple hello word code but it says select python interpreter i have added the path where my interpreter is saved and retied to run code using vs command line but this error comes
have also uninstalled and installed both python and its extension and vs code but still error occurs